# Eigenstates of a Hamiltonian diagonal in momentum basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, spin-models

Suppose we have a 1D Hamiltonian diagonal in $k$-space: $$ H = \sum_k \omega(k) \sigma_k^+ \sigma_k^-, \quad \sigma_k^- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{-i k j} \sigma_j^-,$$ where $k = 0, 2\pi/N , \ldots, (N-1) \times 2\pi/N$. Is there a general construction for the $2^N$ eigenstates of such Hamiltonian?

So far I have worked out the eigenstates for all spins up and down, as well as the single-excitation states $\sigma_k^- |{\uparrow}\rangle^{\otimes N}$.

Comment: Perhaps this reformulation helps: *Is there a general construction for the $2^N$ eigenstates of such Hamiltonian?* = *Is this Hamiltonian diagonalizable?*

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite the Hamiltonian as $H = \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_k\,  \omega (k) \, \left(\mathbb{1} + \sigma^z_k \right) = E_0 \mathbb{1} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_k \, \omega (k) \, \sigma^z_k$ and then the $2^N$ eigenstates of $H$ correspond to all possible choices of which $k$ modes are in the $+$ $Z$ state and which are in the $-$ $Z$ state. I guess you've worked out the cases with all modes unoccupied / occupied.

You can label the eigenstates by the "occupations" $n^{\,}_k = 0,1$, where $\sigma^{z}_k \, \left| n^{\,}_k \right\rangle = (-1)^{n^{\,}_k}\, \left| n^{\,}_k \right\rangle $, so that
$$H = \sum\limits_k \, \frac{1}{2} \, \omega(k) \left( 1 + \hat{n}^{\,}_k \right)$$
with corresponding eigenstates
$$\left|n^{\,}_1, \dots, n^{\,}_{N} \right\rangle$$
that specify all $2^N$ possible eigenstates, with energies above.

This is the same result as appeared in my original answer, where I referenced fermions so that the $n$ occupations would make more sense (since I prefer $n=0,1$ occupations over $\sigma=\pm 1$ up/down variables for writing energies of free models).

Comment: The spin Hamiltonian in the question will in general not transform to a free fermion Hamiltonian under the Jordan-Wigner transformation.

Comment: I'm confused what I missed in the mapping?

Comment: Given you don't write down the mapping: No idea. But the Hamiltonian of the OP is clearly not local in real space, but contains longer range hopping  terms (unless $\omega(k)$ is very special). But non-NN hopping terms do not map to free fermions.

Comment: That's because I "did" the JW transform in $k$ space, where it's trivial: $c^{\,}_k = (-1)^{\sum_{p<k} \sigma^{z}_p} \, \sigma^{+}_k$ so that $c^{\dagger}_k c^{\,}_k = \sigma^{+}_k \sigma^{-}_k$...right? It doesn't matter if this model has JW strings in real space...it's free and diagonal in $k$ space (and JW transforms aren't limited to "real" space)? If you're worried about JW strings, you can use $\sigma^z_k$ instead of $n^{\,}_k = c^{\dagger}_k c^{\,}_k$.

Comment: JW does not transform nicely under Fourier Transforms. That's not what people tpyically would call the JW transform applied to spin chains. In this terminology, the spin Hamiltonian is already diagonal, so I don't see why you would want to apply a JW transform, as it does not change anything.

Comment: I agree JW wasn't necessary and removed it from my answer. Sometimes JW isn't nice under FTs, sure. But you can absolutely define the JW transform in $k$ space. As you can see, the answer without JW is identical. If people think you have to do JW in real space, they are quite simply wrong...who's to decide which one is "real" and which one is "$k$", after all. However, hopefully the edited answer meets with your approval (and I explain that I simply prefer occupations $n=0,1$ over spins $\sigma=\pm 1$).